# The following _CastError was thrown building FutureBuilder<DatabaseNote>

Tags: flutter, dart, dart-null-safety

I am encountering a `_CastError` in Flutter and I'm not sure what can cause it :

```
═══════ Exception caught by widgets library ═══════════════════════════════════
The following _CastError was thrown building FutureBuilder<DatabaseNote>(dirty, state: _FutureBuilderState<DatabaseNote>#aa5d0):
type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'DatabaseNote' in type cast

The relevant error-causing widget was
FutureBuilder<DatabaseNote>
package:mynotes/…/notes/new_note_view.dart:84
When the exception was thrown, this was the stack
```

Here is my code :

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:mynotes/services/auth/auth_service.dart';
import 'package:mynotes/services/crud/notes_service.dart';

class NewNoteView extends StatefulWidget {
  const NewNoteView({super.key});

  @override
  State<NewNoteView> createState() => _NewNoteViewState();
}

class _NewNoteViewState extends State<NewNoteView> {
  DatabaseNote? _note;
  late final NotesService _notesService;
  late final TextEditingController _textController;

  @override
  void initState() {
    _notesService = NotesService();
    _textController = TextEditingController();
    super.initState();
  }

  void _textControllerListener() async {
    final note = _note;
    if (note == null) {
      return;
    }
    final text = _textController.text;
    await _notesService.updateNote(
      note: note,
      text: text,
    );
  }

  void _setupTextControllerListener() {
    _textController.removeListener(_textControllerListener);
    _textController.addListener(_textControllerListener);
  }

  Future<DatabaseNote> createNewNote() async {
    final existingNote = _note;
    if (existingNote != null) {
      return existingNote;
    }
    final currentUser = AuthService.firebase().currentUser!;
    final email = currentUser.email!;
    final owner = await _notesService.getUser(email: email);
    return await _notesService.createNote(owner: owner);
  }

  void _deleteNoteIfTextIsEmpty() {
    final note = _note;
    if (_textController.text.isEmpty && note != null) {
      _notesService.deleteNote(id: note.id);
    }
  }

  void _saveNoteIfTextNotEmpty() async {
    final note = _note;
    final text = _textController.text;
    if (note != null && text.isNotEmpty) {
      await _notesService.updateNote(
        note: note,
        text: text,
      );
    }
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _deleteNoteIfTextIsEmpty();
    _saveNoteIfTextNotEmpty();
    _textController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('New Note'),
      ),
      body: FutureBuilder(
        future: createNewNote(),
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          switch (snapshot.connectionState) {
            case ConnectionState.done:
              _note = snapshot.data as DatabaseNote;
              _setupTextControllerListener();
              return TextField(
                controller: _textController,
                keyboardType: TextInputType.multiline,
                maxLines: null,
                decoration: const InputDecoration(
                  hintText: 'Start typing your note...',
                ),
              );
            default:
              return const CircularProgressIndicator();
          }
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: As the error is explaining FutureBuilder is expecting a value DatabaseNote but is receiving null, for some reason it is not receiving anything...

Comment: Null check is still new to me...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, this error indicates that when building the `FutureBuilder` widget's `builder`, you perform a cast to an explicitly non-null object, which **is in fact null**.

You may replace :

```dart
_note = snapshot.data as DatabaseNote;
```

with

```dart
_note = snapshot.data as DatabaseNote?;
```

Also, you need to make sure that your `Future<DatabaseNote> createNewNote()` method **always** returns a `DatabaseNote` (ie. non-null). Otherwise you may replace its signature by `Future<DatabaseNote?> createNewNote()`.

When writing Dart code, you should always keep in mind your object's nullability and explicitly state it in your code to prevent such errors.

> **Null safety prevents errors that result from unintentional access of variables set to null.** For example, if a method expects an integer but receives null, your app causes a runtime error. This type of error, a null dereference error, can be difficult to debug.
>
> Source: https://dart.dev/null-safety